# How to count words with one syllable in a list of strings of one word using regular expressions

Tags: regex, list, python-2.7

I'm trying to count the number of words, in a pretty long text, that have one syllable. This was defined as words that have zero or more consonants followed by 1 or more vowels followed by zero or more consonants.
The text has been lowercased and split into a list of strings of single words.  Yet everytime I try to use RE's to get the count I get an error because the object is a list and not a string. 
How would I do this in a list?

```
f = open('pg36.txt')
war = f.read()
warlow = war.lower()
warsplit = warlow.split()
import re
def syllables():
  count = len(re.findall('[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*[aeiou]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*', warsplit))
  return count
  print (count)
syllables()
```

Comment: provide an example along with expected output.

Comment: `Yet everytime I try to use RE's to get the count I get an error because the object is a list and not a string`, show your code.

Comment: just put it up @AvinashRaj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're trying to use findall function against  the list not the string, since `findall` works only against the string . So you could try the below.

```
import re
f = open('file')
war = f.read()
warlow = war.lower()
warsplit = warlow.split()
def syllables():
    count = 0
    for i in warsplit:
        if re.match(r'^[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*[aeiou]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*$', i):
            count += 1
    return count
print syllables()
f.close()
```

**OR**

Use findall function directly on `warlow` variable.

```
import re
f = open('file')
war = f.read()
warlow = war.lower()
print len(re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*[aeiou]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*(?!\S)', warlow))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex instead:

`^[^aeiouAEIOU]*[aeiouAEIOU]+[^aeiouAEIOU]*$`

Comment: This is matching `,;:!*% ()_123aeiou$*#{[|`